# How do I insert an element before everything else on a document?

Tags: javascript, dom

I don't think I can use `insertBefore()` because I do not know what element will be first in the DOM.

#### Edit:

I am trying to insert a body tag (i.e. `<body>`).

Comment: You can look in the DOM and find the first element, and then use that ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without using a library, try this:

```
document.body.insertBefore(document.createElement("div"), document.body.firstChild);
```

Comment: the problem is i was trying to insert the body because these pages do not have a body

Comment: Pages **have** to have a body (and since the start and end tags are optional for the body element, a browser should generate one automatically).

Comment: @user521180 Is this an XML document?  If not, how are you rendering a page without a body?

Answer (score 4):

Well, but you can always check this:

- **If document body has at least one child**, use `document.body.insertBefore([the new element], document.body.firstChild)`
- **If document body has no children**, just use `document.body.appendChild([the new element])`.

Answer (score 2):

The first element in the document will be `document.body.children[0]`.

Comment: That will be the first node, which might not be an element (`<body>foo<p>bar</p></body>`). `.firstChild` is nicer though.

Answer (score 0):

Use `prepend()` to add an element to the beginning of a container (the body). http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

`$('body').prepend()`

Comment: The OP didn't say anything about jQuery.

Comment: You're right. I assumed `insertBefore()` was the JQuery function, not the DOM function.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.innerHTML = '<body>'+document.body.innerHTML+'</body>';
```

There. Simply envelops the current HTML with the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.insertBefore()](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/insertBefore) method

```
document.body.insertBefore(newNode, document.body.children[0])
```